# Source for Rava's first name

Tags: sources-mekorot, names, rabbis, amoroim

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rava_(amora)) and [Encyclopedia.com](https://www.encyclopedia.com/religion/encyclopedias-almanacs-transcripts-and-maps/rava), Rava's real first name was Abba and "Rava" is a portmanteau of R' Abba. However, both claims are sourceless (Encyclopedia.com refers to [Eruvin 54a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Eruvin.54a.22?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&with=all&lang=he) but that just gives the name of Rava's father). Is there any source for this claim?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The source is the [Aruch](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_HeArukh%2C_Letter_Alef.31?vhe=Sefer_HeArukh,_Lublin_1883&lang=he) in the name of Rav Sherira and Rav Hai Gaon:

> ורבה ורבא אבא ואבא שמותיהן כאשר הוא ברור דאמר רב נחמן דנייח ליה לאבא וזה רי"ש שבראש המילה סימן היא לרב ולישנא קלילא וכן ראמי בר חמא אמי שמו ומפורש תלמוד בכמה מקומות היינו דשמעינן ליה לאמי ראבין אבין שמו אבין תכלא אבין דסמכ' אבון אחי הרבה כן בתלמוד רב בון אבון שמו רבינא אבינא שמו אשי ואבינא סוף הורא' (פסחים פט) מאה פפי ולא חד אבינא וכן כל כיוצא באלו כגון רחבה רב אהבה הוא וכגון רפרם